# Azure REST API list key vault secrets has maxresults limited to 25

Tags: azure, powershell, rest, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to get a list of all the secrets in each of my key vaults and I'm using Microsofts documentation at this URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecrets/getsecrets#secretlistresult

It states that if you do not set maxresults it will default to 25. It does however throw this error in my powershell script when i try to set it higher than 25.

```json
{"error":{"code":"BadParameter","message":"invalid maxresults"}}
```

From the documentation the endpoint does not appear to contain any pagination or way to get more than 25 random secrets. This seems to make the endpoint pretty useless as there are no ways to filter the listings.

The command I'm using to get the list is this.

```
$uri = ""https://$($Vault).vault.azure.net/secrets?api-version=7.1&maxresults=26""
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
```

Comment: Do you not get `nextLink` in the response body?

Comment: It returns a value field which contains a list of id and attributes for each of the 25 secrets.

Comment: And I'm stupid and nextLink was being hidden because I was formatting the output as a table.

Answer (score 0):

As Gaurav said in the comment, you need to use [`nextLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecrets/getsecrets#secretlistresult) to get the result of next page.

There is my test code with `do-until`:

```
$LoginUrl = "https://login.microsoft.com"
$RresourceUrl = "https://vault.azure.net/.default"
$ClientID = ""
$ClientSecret = ""
$TenantName = ""

# Compose REST request.
$Body = @{ grant_type = "client_credentials"; scope = $RresourceUrl; client_id = $ClientID; client_secret = $ClientSecret }     
$OAuth = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $LoginUrl/$TenantName/oauth2/v2.0/token -Body $Body

# Check if authentication was successfull.
if ($OAuth.access_token) {
    # Format headers.
    $HeaderParams = @{
        'Content-Type'  = "application\json"
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $($OAuth.access_token)"
    }

    # Create an empty array to store the result.
    $QueryResults = @()
    
    $Uri = "https://<your-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/secrets?api-version=7.1"
    # Invoke REST method and fetch data until there are no pages left.
    do {
        
        $Results = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $HeaderParams -Uri $Uri -UseBasicParsing -Method "GET" -ContentType "application/json"
        $Results.nextLink
        if ($Results.value) {
            $QueryResults += $Results.value
        }
        else {
            $QueryResults += $Results
        }
        $Uri = $Results.nextLink
    } until (!($Uri))

    # Return the result.
    $QueryResults
}
else {
    Write-Error "No Access Token"
}
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.